# How to include directories while debugging and testing a gem

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rubygems, require, testunit

Can anybody throw me a line?

I'm having problems in tests implementation, concretely, while requiring files.

I am developing a gem called mme_tools with a directory tree like this. The initial scaffold was generated using *jeweler*.

```
mme_tools
|-- examples
|   |-- demo_enumerable.rb
|   `-- demo_print_debug.rb
|-- Gemfile
|-- Gemfile.lock
|-- lib
|   |-- mme_tools
|   |   |-- concurrent.rb
|   |   |-- debug.rb
|   |   |-- enumerable.rb
|   |   |-- version.rb
|   |   `-- webparse.rb
|   `-- mme_tools.rb
|-- LICENSE.txt
|-- Rakefile
|-- README.rdoc
`-- test
    `-- test_mme_tools.rb
```

where, **mme_tools.rb** is simply a container that requires all the files in **mme_tools** subdir (i.e. `require 'mme_tools/debug.rb'`).

In the **examples** dir I can make some untidy tests (demos) as I progress. Simply putting a `require 'mme_tools'` at the top of each of those demos, and running ruby with option `-I../lib` works OK. In fact, I use Netbeans to develop so I include that option in every run.

My problem arises while testing. At the top of **test_mme_tools.rb** I have

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'mme_tools'
```

but my tests don't work because I think **mme_tools.rb** isn't found. The output from the rake task that I run from the shell is:

```
$ rake test
rake/rdoctask is deprecated.  Use rdoc/task instead (in RDoc 2.4.2+)
/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -I"lib:lib:test" -I"/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib" "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/**/test_*.rb" 
Loaded suite /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started
E
Finished in 0.02176 seconds.

  1) Error:
test_compose(TC_MMETools):
NoMethodError: undefined method `compose' for MMETools::Enumerable:Module
    /mnt/dropbox/DESENVOLUPAMENT/Gems/mme_tools/test/test_mme_tools.rb:19:in `test_compose'

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/usr/bin/ruby1.8 -I"lib:lib:test" -I"/usr/...]

Tasks: TOP => test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Of course, from Netbeans occurs the same, exceptuating that it shows the full trace

The file **test_mme_tools.rb** is as follows:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'mme_tools'

class TC_MMETools < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    @a=(1..12)
    @b=("A".."M")
    @c=%w{tantmateix adhuc nogensmenys urgell pocassolta carrincló bajanada casundena Massalcoreig}
  end

  def test_compose
    assert_equal [2,"B","adhuc"], MMETools::Enumerable.compose(@a,@b,@c)[1]
  end

end
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you continue with Rake, and update to use minitest, you can use a Rakefile that looks like this:

```
require 'rake/testtask'
Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << 'lib'
  t.pattern = 'test/**/*.rb'
end
```